# Why does this div not load consistently in Chrome? A bug?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, browser-bugs

I have Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m running on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit

I created this WP plugin a couple years ago that works just fine (could certainly use improvement) that shows a cached, stylized Google Calendar.  When I dropped it into another website today I was faced with apparent browser drawing errors, but only on this one website, which leads me to believe there is some sort of CSS conflict.

I zipped the plugin in its entirety from http://ebcbuffalo.com/calendar/ (which displays without any errors in the same browser) and installed it on the new website: http://faithbaptistspringville.com/monthly-calendar/.  As you can see, they look identical.

When I click on an event in the calendar on the latter, it may or may not draw the div properly, and even if it does draw it properly, after closing the event and clicking on more events always causes draw errors.  When it doesn't draw properly, to see the div as it should be, I simply click on another tab in Chrome then click back to that tab.  Bingo--it's there (until I scroll down and it looks as though it's absolute-positioned, when in fact it's fixed, then try clicking on its links and they...AREN'T REALLY THERE).

I thought maybe something was fishy with my JS so I ran the most basic command from my Chrome console: `jQuery('#id_popup').show();` and `jQuery('#id_popup').hide();` but it behaves just as weirdly.

I'm convinced it's a bug with Chrome, but why does it only infect this one website (faithbaptistspringville.com)?

Here's the working one:
[image: No bug]

Here's 2 screenshots of the bug (it's completely random in how it redraws)
[image: Bug view #1]
[image: Bug view #2]

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug as you described, on my side, the popup loads **very slowly** making the page white out for a long time (while the page at the first link works OK). Looks like it's the bug in your code. Tested both in Chrome and Opera.

Comment: After along time, the popup shows as you described, looks like a bug, but even worse, I can't close it right, the X close button seems to not be interative **for a moment** ... So it's hard to say what causes this while I think it may be caused by the code.

Comment: Did you try the 'switch to a different tab and back' trick?

Comment: Alternatively to switching to a different tab, I can just select a large area of the page and it draws it properly usually.

Comment: I think you fire the popup with ajax request as showing in this snapshot http://i.imgur.com/6iz6RWS.png . If so, there's a solution but am not sure about it . Try to set `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` to your popup div `#id_popup` .

Comment: Ah yeah, I understand it, in fact you don't need to switch the tab, after clicking a while, just try selecting (using mouse) the center area and you'll see the popup - so weird

Comment: I tested on IE 10, FF 28 and the latest version of the very young browser Maxthon, it works OK on those browsers **but** not in Chrome and Opera, looks like it's a bug however I think you can edit your code to make it work cross-browser.

Comment: @Mahmoud Thanks but that didn't do it.  Indeed, it runs an AJAX call to the cached version of the Google Calendar on this server.

Comment: That's weird! what if we set `min-height`. I hope can help.

Comment: No sir: It still fails.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really figure out why this fixes it, but in my chrome (which reproduced the issue) I resolved the issue by changing the css in devtools for `#id_popup` to use `position: absolute;` instead of fixed.

Comment: If the `#id_popup` is for the popup showing the info after clicking on the test link, I think `fixed` is the right style for it, if you set it as absolute, you may want to try scrolling the page to the bottom and clicking the test link? it should not be centered on the screen anymore.

Comment: I see it - maybe some jquery could test for scroll and amend the `top` accordingly? Horrible I know, but it might get round this very weird bug

Comment: I could get the same centering effect by positioning it with jQuery as I did on the calendar agenda on the home page of http://hotoffthepresspaninis.com/, but I shouldn't NEED to just to get it working.